# Python, numba, class with field of its own type

Tags: python, numba

I'm trying to use numba's `jitclass` on a class that has a field of its own type.

The below code does not work because `Foo` is not defined.

```
from numba.experimental import jitclass

@jitclass
class Foo:
    a: int
    pred: 'Foo'

    def __init__(self, pred: 'Foo'):
        self.a = 1
        self.pred = pred


if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = Foo(None)
```

Replacing `Foo` with object also does not work. Additionally, I need to be able to pass None in one instance.

Is there a way to make this work?

The only other idea I have is to store `pred` in an external dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
from numba.experimental import jitclass
from numba import deferred_type, int64, optional

foo_type = deferred_type()

spec = dict()
spec['a'] = int64
spec['pred'] = optional(foo_type)


@jitclass(spec)
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, pred):
        self.a = 1
        self.pred = pred

foo_type.define(Foo.class_type.instance_type)

x = Foo(None)
y = Foo(x)
```

It is based on [this example](https://github.com/numba/numba/blob/fdbe264706881d19e97494e5ca794c540479a4d0/examples/linkedlist.py).